# What does this panic reboot tell me about my machine?

Tags: google-chrome, kernel-panic

Do I have a hardware problem or a software problem with Chrome?

```
Anonymous UUID:       C271640C-6221-F912-87B0-60096E95829B

Thu Apr 19 09:48:07 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff800c67edcc): "No more room to grow table: 0x0xffffff800d03fee0 size:262142, used:262141, requested elem:1"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.51.1/osfmk/kern/ltable.c:461
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff921537b920 : 0xffffff800c66e166 
0xffffff921537b970 : 0xffffff800c796714 
0xffffff921537b9b0 : 0xffffff800c788a00 
0xffffff921537ba30 : 0xffffff800c620180 
0xffffff921537ba50 : 0xffffff800c66dbdc 
0xffffff921537bb80 : 0xffffff800c66d99c 
0xffffff921537bbe0 : 0xffffff800c67edcc 
0xffffff921537bc70 : 0xffffff800c6b5924 
0xffffff921537bc90 : 0xffffff800c65946d 
0xffffff921537bce0 : 0xffffff800cb04acf 
0xffffff921537bd90 : 0xffffff800cb03a20 
0xffffff921537bee0 : 0xffffff800cb05fb0 
0xffffff921537bf40 : 0xffffff800cc04418 
0xffffff921537bfa0 : 0xffffff800c620966 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Google Chrome He

Mac OS version:
17E199

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar  5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1B55340B-0B14-3026-8A47-1E139DB63DA3
Kernel slide:     0x000000000c400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800c600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800c500000
System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 164812007998412
last loaded kext at 94087658167257: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   92 (addr 0xffffff7f8ffc1000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 93951443226963: com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport  1404.3 (addr 0xffffff7f8ff82000, size 90112)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.2.4
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   92
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.33
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   281.51
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   281.51
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.18.48
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.18.48
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.5f3
com.apple.GeForce   10.3.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.18.48
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 254
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  254
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.50.6
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.51.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1240.19.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329.50.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   220.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1404.4
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1404.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  205
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   205
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.51
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 675.6
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   675.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.3.0
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.18.48
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.51
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.51
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   519.15
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.18.48
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    378.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   211.12
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.18.48
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    519.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 261
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.50.10
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.50.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.50.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    675.12
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00F5.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.190.18.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.5f3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Composite Device
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Comment: "no more room" sounds like a memory or storage problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google Chrome ran out of space to insert records into some sort of table.

Comment: This reply does not supply an answer and should not have been offered as one. As can be determined from the first sentence in the post, WilliamKF is already aware of the possibility of a software issue on the part of Google Chrome Helper.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today, but related to `logd` process. I have the same MacOS and Kernel versions. Looks like Mac OS problem:

[Crash with error "Panic. No more room to grow table" (logd thread)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/323504/crash-with-error-panic-no-more-room-to-grow-table-logd-thread)