# Crash with error "Panic. No more room to grow table" (logd thread)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, kernel-panic

MacOS crashed with this error. Is it hardware or software issue?

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff800027edcc): "No more room to grow table: 0x0xffffff8000c3fee0 size:262142, used:262141, requested elem:1"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.51.1/osfmk/kern/ltable.c:461
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9228c7b830 : 0xffffff800026e166 
0xffffff9228c7b880 : 0xffffff8000396714 
0xffffff9228c7b8c0 : 0xffffff8000388a00 
0xffffff9228c7b940 : 0xffffff8000220180 
0xffffff9228c7b960 : 0xffffff800026dbdc 
0xffffff9228c7ba90 : 0xffffff800026d99c 
0xffffff9228c7baf0 : 0xffffff800027edcc 
0xffffff9228c7bb80 : 0xffffff80002b5924 
0xffffff9228c7bba0 : 0xffffff80004d9210 
0xffffff9228c7bbf0 : 0xffffff80004d90af 
0xffffff9228c7bc30 : 0xffffff8000705b44 
0xffffff9228c7bd20 : 0xffffff800070510d 
0xffffff9228c7bd90 : 0xffffff8000703d3a 
0xffffff9228c7bee0 : 0xffffff80007060b5 
0xffffff9228c7bf40 : 0xffffff8000804418 
0xffffff9228c7bfa0 : 0xffffff8000220966 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: logd

Mac OS version:
17E199

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar  5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1B55340B-0B14-3026-8A47-1E139DB63DA3
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8000100000
System model name: MacBookPro14,3 (Mac-551B86E5744E2388)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 295742898381219
last loaded kext at 293880634196283: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f83278000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 294477932559173: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8326c000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.6.6
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   1.6.6
...
```